# Convention for value in static transform publisher node

Tags: ros, static-transform-publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to check my understanding, whether it is right or wrong regarding the parameter value when using static_transform_publisher node [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/tf#static_transform_publisher). For example, like below:

```
<node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="base_link_to_laser" 
  args="1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 /base_link /laser 40" />
```

So, the x-value set there as 1.0 is in meter right?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12222/convention-for-value-in-static-transform-publisher-node/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2011-12-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is correct, all distance/length measurements are in meters, angles are in radians. In general you should reference [Standard Units of Measure and Coordinate Conventions](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0103.html) document is you have any doubts about units.

---

Originally posted by [arebgun](https://answers.ros.org/users/18/arebgun/) with karma: 2121 on 2011-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4